# Issue -RadGridView - GridViewDateTimeColumn editor does not allow max value 09/09/9999

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, telerik-grid

**To Reproduce**:
 1. Add a GridViewDateTimeColumn to a RadGridView.
 2. Try to set RadDateTimeEditor.MaxValue in CellEditorInitialized event to 31/12/9999. 
 3. As a result, ArgumentOutOfRangeException("MaxDate cannot be higher
    than the max date") is thrown

[image: image not found]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: obviously the editor max value is naot the same as the .net datetime maxvalue - check their docs

Comment: Hi @JohnB - As I mentioned I just want to increase the Max Limit of the DateTime column in Telerik Grid. So that grid would accept '09/09/9999' date as a valid date. Currently, it is not accepting the date greater than the '31/12/9998'.

Answer (score 0):

For your case with GridDateTimeColumn you should use the SharedCalendar property of the RadDatePicker. The SharedCalendar property holds a shared instance of the calendar in order to speed up performance when we use the calendar on many places. This is the case with the grid having multiple items each having a calendar, that is why the GridDateTimeColumn makes use of the SharedCalendar property instead of the standard one.

Also here the relevant property for the maximum date is called RangeMaxDate

```
RadDatePicker rdp = cell.Controls[0] as RadDatePicker;
rdp.SharedCalendar.RangeMaxDate = setMaxDate;
```

Comment: Hi JohnB, It might be a silly question but can you please tell which event we can use to execute the above code. Also, I am not able to find RadDatePicker. Thanks!